# Як перекласти з російської "пододеяльник"?

Tags: переклад, from-russian

Я періодично натрапляю на переклади "підковдра" або "підперина", але, чесно кажучи, ні разу не чула їх у загальному вжитку. Тож питання швидше не про те, яка відповідь правильна "за словником", а про те, як, власне, говорять у побуті.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Колись я вже бачив обговорення цього питання в інших місцях ([1](http://maidan.org.ua/arch/mova/1280993726.html), [2](http://r2u.org.ua/forum/viewtopic.php?t=553), [3](https://www.facebook.com/groups/ukrpereklad/permalink/921344197901349/), [4](https://www.facebook.com/groups/ukrpereklad/permalink/1108771372491963/)). Підсумовуючи їх, я колись створив такий список слів, що їх люди *хоч десь* чули в значенні чохла на ковдру:

> - підодіяльник
>   - пододеяльник
>
> - підковдра
>   - поковдра
>   - наковдра
>   - наковдрик
>
> - наковдерник
>   - наковдреник
>   - наковдряник
>   - підковдряник
>
> - навкривало
>   - підукри́вало
>   - підпокривало
>
> - пішва
>   - по́шва
>   - пішивка
>   - по́шивка
>
> - наволочка
>   - напірник
>
> - обго́ртень
>   *<sub>(1. Я намагався додавати лише варіанти, що люди **десь чули**, а не просто **пропонують** — але я міг не завжди правильно інтерпретувати наміри людей.
>
>   2. Тут присутні варіанти, якими можуть називати інші предмети постільної білизни — це **не помилка** в переліку, а у відповідності до тверждення людини, що хтось називає цим словом **і чохол на ковдру теж**.)</sub>*

Я не можу оцінити вживаність всіх цих варіантів у розмовній мові, але можу оцінити вживаність деяких з них у письмових джерелах, що, очевидно, має хоч трішки корелювати з розмовною мовою:

1. **Підодіяльник** є навіть в словнику [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/pidodijaljnyk), але без прикладів вживання, що незвично для СУМ-11, але недивно в цілому, бо в художній літературі майже не зустрічається (41 результат в Google Books). Деякі приклади вживань (не повний перелік і не лише художні):

   - Побіжи, Тонику, швидше до Олени Іванівни і скажи, щоб дала чисте простирадло, підодіяльник, наволочку, і принеси все це у кімнату Софії Миронівни. *<sub>//О. Іваненко «Рiднi дiти» (1968).</sub>*
   - Накрохмалений підодіяльник шурхотить дужче, ніж газети, скинуті після вчорашнього читання на килимок. *<sub>//В. Синенко «Злітають проти вітру» (1970).</sub>*
   - <sub>[…]; оно за хлівом жовтіє заміс глини з кізяками, на дубовому порозі барвистіє трап’яний килимок і галоші пахнуть риб’ячим слизом, оно в канаві на лопухах і на колесі від воза заскліла роса, під плотом залатаний бляхою човен ховає мишачий писк, шелепоче сухими стручками акація, старі довіковують, нема поживи, оно по вулиці вітер скубе забуту в поштовій скриньці газету, надуває і хмарить підодіяльники на шпагаті, мотузить прищепки на пелюшках, онуця підкинули, плакало наше молочко, оно височіє лободина на купі битої цегли, пахне цементом від мішків під повіткою і м’яко, буцім шешітка в соснині, вгинається тирса за пилорамою, тутай на молочарню здають, будуються ж! […]!</sub> *<sub>//Є. Пашковський «Вовча Зоря» (1991).</sub>*
   - Пам'ятаю[,] як перестеляла ліжка[,] то брала простиньку чи підодіяльник і робили такий собі «гамак»[,] куда [куди] кидали одного з наших котиків і устроювали [влаштовували] йому каруселі. *<sub>//Допис на форумі, в Інтернеті (2007).</sub>*
   - Всовувати ковдру до підодіяльника. *<sub>//А. Чех «Сині двері зліва» (2009).</sub>*
   - Одна ковдра, другу дадуть, але за підодіяльник треба заплатити 50 гр. *<sub>//Відгук про хостел, в Інтернеті (2012).</sub>*
   - Коли вона підтягувала підодіяльник, то на мить здалося, що він важчий ніж зазвичай. *<sub>//Переклад Г. Пагутяк твору З. Ітсміолорд «Паперові янголи», в Інтернеті (2009).</sub>*
   - Три елемента [елементи], які входять в комплект мають розміри необхідні для ліжечка 120 на 60, а саме простирадло (148 х 95 см), підодіяльник (120 х 90 см) і наволочка (62 х 38 см). *<sub>//Опис товару, в Інтернеті (2014).</sub>*
2. **Підковдра** теж є в словнику [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/pidkovdra), але знов таки без прикладів вживання, що знов таки незвично для СУМ-11; в художній літературі зустрічається ще рідше за «підодіяльник» (11 результатів в Google Books). Деякі приклади вживань (не повний перелік і не лише художні):

   - Сава з готовністю людини, яка служила в армії, встав і потягнув замок-блискавку. Зверху лежала колись блискучо-біла, а зараз тьмяно-біла підковдра , скручена в сувій, бо Сава віз білизну, щоб жінка чи її мати випрала. *<sub>//В. Рубан «Помирав уражений проліском сніг» (1970).</sub>*
   - Зазвичай діє наступне правило – підковдра має бути на 5 см менше самої ковдри. *<sub>//Стаття, в Інтернеті (2011).</sub>*
   - 1 повний постільний комплект (ковдра, подушка, вам знадобляться значно пізніше, а от бампер і балдахін будуть до речі, простирадло і підковдра само собою. До речі про балдахін – віддавайте перевагу сітчатому – він створює тінь і водночас добре пропускає повітря, але в будь-якому разі його слід часто прати). *<sub>//Стаття, в Інтернеті (2012).</sub>*
   - А в мене вилетів з голови Маньчин метод порятунку від комарів шляхом загортання у підковдри. *<sub>//М. Гончарова «Формула щастя Наріне Абгарян», стаття в «Дзеркалі тижня» (2012).</sub>*
   - Клаптикова ковдра — з пропаленими корупцією дірками, з брудними плямами безгосподарності і без підковдри цільного законодавства. *<sub>//В. Самар «П'ять причин, чому Україна повинна різко змінити політику щодо Криму», стаття в «Дзеркалі тижня» (2016).</sub>*
3. **Наковдра** — її пошук в Інтернеті знаходить лише двічі:

   - В *одному* Інтернет-магазині мається майже послідовно для позначення товарів даного виду (≈50% випадків — наковдра, інші — підковдра).
   - В спільноті «Чехія & Чеська мова», навчаючи базовим чеським словам, пишуть: «підковдра, наковдра – cícha».
4. **Наковдерник** пошук в Інтернеті знаходить теж лише двічі, зате один з них — у виданому журналі:

   - Торкаю мережку на краю подушки, наковдерник і гладеньку атласову   ковдру у квадратному викроєнні, знаю, що вона повинна бути золотаво-жовтого  кольору. *<sub>//Л. Палій «Такі дивні сни», в журналі «Сучасність» (1993, № 8)).</sub>*
   - Для ночування в хаті потрібно мати з собою постіль (простирало, наковдерник і наподушник або спальник) - в мене там немає пральної машинки і все прання я везу прати до Львова. *<sub>//Допис на форумі, в Інтернеті (2015).</sub>*
5. **Наковдреник** пропонує [П. Федотюк в «Етюдах про мову» (журнал «Вітчизна», 2007, № 1–2)](http://vitchyzna.ukrlife.org/1_2_07fedotyuk.htm), але пошук в Інтернеті не знаходить траплянь взагалі, окрім згадок в темах, подібних до даної (хоча дві з них начебто кажуть про практичне застосування: «Взагалі-то „підковдра“. Але хтось у нас жартома сказав „наковдреник“. Жарти жартами, а воно у нас в сім'ї прижилося...» та «а підковдра легітимне слово? Я знаю наковдреник, а от підковдру вперше :)»).
6. **Наковдряник** пошук в Інтернеті знаходить лише одноразово:

   - Знімає і кладе на стілець ковдру, подушку, простирадло, знімає наковдряник. *<sub>//Реферат, в Інтернеті.</sub>*
7. **Підковдряник** пошук в Інтернеті знаходить лише одноразово:

   - Привезено з Китаю / Було продано як шовк, але це не він, тому віддаємо / Велика простиня і підковдряник — більше[,] ніж стандартна двоспальна / + наволочки (2 прямокутні і 2 маленькі квадратна) / колір передано вірно: беж з відливом[.] *<sub>//Оголошення, в Інтернеті.</sub>*
8. **Підукри́вало** є в [«Російсько-українському словнику» О. Ізюмова (1930)](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE&dicts=2) та згадується в книжці М. Лисюка «Доля моєї мови», тим не менш пошук в Інтернеті, окрім вищезгаданих, знаходить лише одноразово:

   - Нагадування: До табору лишився 1 день! Виїжджаємо о 12:00. Не забудьте взяти з собою постіль (підукривало, наволочку, простирадло), та рюкзак з Біблією. Щасливого польоту. *<sub>//Форумний допис, в Інтернеті (2016).</sub>*
9. **Підпокривало** пошук в Інтернеті знаходить лише одноразово, зате у виданому художньому творі, але не факт, що значення саме те:

   - В ту мить Марта невиразно відчула холод, бо лежала горілиць розкрита, зібгавши в ногах ковдру й підпокривало. *<sub>//В. Підмогильний «Невеличка драма», в журналі «Життя й революція» (1930, № 3–6).</sub>*
10. *П{і,о}шва*, *п{і,о}шивка*, а також *наволочка* і *напірник* — їх важко відслідкувати в Інтернеті, оскільки основним значенням цих слів, як я розумію, є не чохол на ковдру, а чолол на подушку чи перину, або просто «шов для зшивання двох шматків» ([у Грінченка про пішву](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/39744-pishva.html)). Тим не менш я припускаю, що у когось, можливо, це означає саме чохол на ковдру, або просто чохол на будь-яких предмет постелі в широкому значенні — особливо вірогідним це вважаю для перших двох. Одначе мені просто сталі ліньки відслідковувати.
11. Всі інші слова з верхнього переліку я взагалі не знаходив в Інтернеті, окрім, можливо, тем, подібних до цієї.

P.S.: «Українсько-російський словник (за новим правописом)» О. Ізюмова (1930, Харків–Київ, не плутати з його ж рос.-укр. словником) в якості відповідника рос. «пододеяльник» надає **налі́жник** (а не «підукри́вало»; а [тут](http://forum.maidan.org.ua/T-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%97-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BB) також стверджують, що в його ж «Правописному словнику» 1931 року ці два слова показані як синоніми — але цього я вже особисто не зміг перевірити). Але сучасне значення слова «наліжник» — це, наскільки я знаю, радше покривало. Крім того, оскільки від жодної людини тверджень про те, що вона використовує це слово в значенні чохла на ковдру, я не чув, то, відповідно до питання автора про побут, а не про словники, я «наліжника» не подаю ані у верхньому, ані у нижньому переліку.

Comment: Ще, маючи на увазі «підодіяльник», інколи вживають загальне  «постіль».

Comment: Щодо *наволочки* й *напірника*. Пам'ятаю, як бабуся робила подушки й перини з пуху й пір'я пташиного, то *напірником* був перший чохол, з грубішої тканини, який наглухо зашивався і не знімався. А *наволочка* - це другий чохол на подушку, з тонкої тканини, який надягається поверх напірника і знімається для прання. Ще були декоративні вишиті наволочки, якими вбирали декоративні подушки. Це ж підтверджує і СУМ: [напірник](http://sum.in.ua/s/napirnyk), [наволочка](http://sum.in.ua/s/navolochka).

Comment: До речі, приклади використання _підковдра_  можна зустріти на цінниках в одному будівельному гіпермаркеті.

Comment: @BohdanKuts, якому? Взагалі, те, що пишуть на цінниках — не завжди показник правильності (я бачив на цінниках, наприклад, «куліч» — причому якби це стосувалося російської кухні, то це можна було б зрозуміти, але там було щось типу «куліч по-міланськи»). Але якщо скажете конкретну назву — додам це у відповідь.

Comment: @Sasha, бачив таке в Епіцентрі. Я не кажу чи це правильно, а наводжу це як приклад використання. Ось додатково посилання як приклад: https://27.ua/ua/search/?sect=3811&q=%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0

Comment: якось багато тексту...

Comment: @ВіталійМацкевич, а маєте конкретні поради щодо того, які частини тексту варто прибрати?

Comment: НАКОВДРЕНИК, мабуть, буде найліпшим відповідником. Плюсанув за варіант 5.

Answer (score 12):

У програмі "Експрес-урок української" Олександр Авраменко вказує, що найбільш доцільно використовувати "підковдра", коли ми говоримо про легкий чохол, який одягають на ковдру.
Вживаність по регіонам цього терміна не вказана.

Посилання на відео програми: [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GaTIFhJ-FLM)

Answer (score 9):

"Підковдра" (як і "підперина") виглядає семантичною калькою, бо насправді воно ж не "під" ковдрою, а вдягається на неї, огортаючи з обох боків, тому так мали би називати простирадло, яке пришивають до ковдри з одного боку, а не чохол.

У лемківській говірці таке значення має слово *пішва* (польською - *poszwa*), але словник Грінченка каже, що це - "шовъ для сшиванія двухъ кусковъ: края сшиваемыхъ кусковъ перегибаются одинъ за другой и сшиваются двойнымъ швомъ".

Логічніше було б назвати цю річ наковдерком, накоцником чи наліжником (але так, мої варіанти не дуже), хоча адекватні слова "напірник" і "наволока" утворено за аналогічною словотвірною моделлю, тож дивно, що укладачі словників на те не зважали.

Comment: шито під ковдру?

Comment: До речі, як я зазначив у постскриптумі до [своєї відповіді](http://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/354/4), «наліжник» подано в укр.-рос. словнику Ізюмова саме як «пододеяльник» — тож один з Ваших варіантів навіть словниковий.

Answer (score 8):

«Підодіяльник», яке дає мій російсько-український словник 1948 року з Максимом Рильським у редколегії, а також [СУМ в 11 томах](http://sum.in.ua/s/pidodijaljnyk), звучить досить впевнено, і слово «одіяло» в українській теж є:

ОДІЯ́ЛО, а, сер. Те саме, що ковдра. *Часто він брав лінійку і виглажував [вигладжував] нею скарбове біле з синіми берегами одіяло так, що на ліжку не було і складочки* (Нечуй-Левицький, I, 1950, 342);

*Підстелю я дочці одіяло, Промінь місяця в ліжко проріс* (Андрій Малишко, Звенигора, 1959, 148).

Джерело: [Словник української мови: в 11 томах. — Том 5, 1974. — Стор. 631.](http://sum.in.ua/s/odijalo)

Answer (score 2):

Мені подобається [пояснення з вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0) згідно якого обидва основні варіанти (`підковдра` та `підодіяльник` ) є похідними від запозичених слів.

> Українське `ковдра` є запозиченням з польської мови — від `kołdra`
>   («ковдра»), звідси також біл. `коўдра` («ковдра») і рос. `колтырь`
>   («сорт сукна»). Польське слово, як вважають, сходить через ст.-іт.
>   `coltra` («покриття», «укривало») і нар.-лат. `culcitra` до лат.
>   `culcita` («подушка», «матрац»)

[Етимологічний словник української мови](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%95%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8): В 7 т. / АН УРСР. Ін-т мовознавства ім. О. О. Потебні; Редкол. О. С. Мельничук (головний ред.) та ін. — Т. 2: Д — Копці / Укл.: Н. С. Родзевич та ін. — 1985. — 572 с.

> Слово `одіяло` запозичене з російської мови — від `одеяло` (у старому
>   правопису `одѣяло`), утвореного від дієслова `одѣять` («одягнути»,
>   «одіти»)

[Етимологічний словник української мови](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%95%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8): В 7 т. / АН УРСР. Ін-т мовознавства ім. О. О. Потебні; Редкол. О. С. Мельничук (головний ред.) та ін. — Т. 4: Н — П / Уклад.: Р. В. Болдирєв та ін.; Ред. тому: В. Т. Коломієць, В. Г. Скляренко. — 2003. — 656 с. ISBN 966-00-0590-3.